# Calculations from elements of two list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have two list of lists

```
lst1=[['1', '1', '0'],['1', '-1', '0'],['1', '0', '-3'],['0', '1', '-0.5']]
lst2=[(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(3,4)]
```

I want to do the multiplication of each element in list1 with lst2.
i.e, 1st elements in the 1st list of lst * all the lists in lst2

```
[1*1+1*1+0, 1*2+1*1+0, 1*3+1*2+0, 1*3+1*4+0]
etc.
```

I converted the first list elements into float and flattened the list of lists into a single list. My logic seems to be wrong. I am stuck here.

can somebody help me with a hint on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses the following operations.

- List comprehension with the outer loop for lst1 and the inner for lst2
- Use of `map(float, l1)` on the elements of the elements of lst1 to convert to `int`
- Concatenation of a 1-element tuple containing the number 0 `l2+(0,)` to create an implicit multiplier for the missing 3rd element in the elements of lst2, with the net effect of ignoring the 3rd element of each triple in lst1.
- Use of `map(mul, ...` to do the multiplication of the triples.
- Using sum to add the triples together to create the final list of results

```
from operator import mul

lst1=[['1', '1', '0'],['1', '-1', '0'],['1', '0', '-3'],['0', '1', '-0.5']]
lst2=[(1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(3,4)]


print([sum(map(mul, map(float, l1), l2+(0,))) for l2 in lst2 for l1 in lst1])
```

Result:

```
[2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 7.0, -1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```